# Folder missing icon

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applecare

When ever I turn on Mac every day at first I see this folder missing icon then I go to safe mode then I restart it works normal.
When I turn on Mac again on next day I get this again and I have to repeat safe mode process again.
I did svc reset and nvram too and even recovery mode process and did a first aid from utility.
Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me I would:

- Make a full backup of my hard drive (if you haven't already got one)
- Reset the NVRAM

If that doesn't resolve the issue, I'd be inclined to investigate replacing your hard drive. However, since you'd have a fresh backup, you could do a full fresh reinstallation of macOS, ensuring that you reformat the drive while you're at it.

**Resetting the NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). Since you haven't specified the exact model of Mac you have, follow these *generic* steps to reset the NVRAM:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* immediately press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.
3. Keep these keys pressed down for **at least 20 seconds!**
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

As I mentioned above, if this doesn't resolve the issue, it's time to try a fresh installation of macOS or replacing your drive.

Comment: I tried nvram but now will try to reinstall os.